# App-scoped IDs in Facebook group members request

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am the administrator of a Facebook group, and I created a site where I use FB login to identify my users; users of the site are supposed to be also members of my FB group.

Before the introduction of version 2.0 of Facebook API I used to store the ID of people logging in through my app in a mySql DB; since API 2.0 app-scoped ID have been created (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#), and I've understood how they work.
I've noticed that users who have logged in after the introduction of 2.0 API have the (longer) app-scoped ID, while old ones are keeping the same old ID (as I expected).

Now my question: I'm writing a small code to check if members of FB group I administrate are users of my site too (i.e. if their IDs have already been stored in my site's database), but I've found that a lot of IDs obtained through this code:

```
$members = $facebook->api('/'.$userGroupId.'/members','GET');       
foreach($members['data'] as $data) {
    echo $data["id"]."<br>"; }
```

are different from the ones I've stored in my DB.

The same user seems to be identified with 2 different IDs, one for login and another one for the group.

So, what's going on? 
I suppose is something related to app-scoped IDs, but so far I haven't found a clear explaination on how FB group members IDs work...

Hope that someone could help me to better understand the logic behind user IDs on Facebook groups.

Comment: Are you using an access token from the same app to make that API call? In that case you should receive the same ID back

Comment: Yes,same app, different ID...

Comment: My supposition: the IDs I stored in my database were mainly of users who logged using version 1.0 of the API; the get request I've made on group members has been made through API 2.0, so all IDs are app-scoped. Maybe IDs of people who will log with 2.0 API will be the same of the ones I get through the request? Both of them app-scoped? At the moment I'm using a table where I stored old and new ID for each user... but it's a really "painful" and troublesome method...